# GitLab certificate is valid for domain.com, not xxx.domain.com

Tags: gitlab

When using docker inside docker to build the packages the gitlab-runner wasn't able to login to my self-hosted gitlab server:

> *docker login xxx.example.com:5050 -u user -p password*
>
> Error response from daemon: Get "https://xxx.example.com:5050/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for **example.com**, not **xxx.example.com**

By default the SSL is enabled with LetsEncrypt and worked perfectly. Inside the official documentation of Gitlab it says the certificate is valid for all subdomains as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation.

**I found out, that we used a different certificate for xxxx.domain.com than the one for domain.com**

After changing the configuration inside the nginx it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have issued a certificate for the “apex” domain (i.e. no subdomain). A normal certificate is not valid for subdomains, only exception is the `www` subdomain. You have three options:

- Create a certificate for `subdomain.example.com`.
- Create a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com`
- Create a multidomain certificate for `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`; potentially for other subdomains as well. Some CAs allow extending a multidomain certificate with additional (sub-)domains later on, but please check in advance.

By the way, consider setting up [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), and you won’t have to worry about issuing more certificates.

Comment: I am using Let's Encrypt. I also read in the Gitlab Documentation that all subdomains are covered. Is there a way to test this?

Comment: There are different certificate viewers that will show you for which domain(s) it is issued. I’m not sure which docs you’ve followed, but clearly a wildcard or multidomain certificate was not created. Please check the LE docs to see how such certs are to be created.

Comment: Hello Lxg, thank you for your help. Here is the Gitlab Documentation:

Let’s Encrypt is enabled by default if external_url is set with the HTTPS protocol and no other certificates are configured.

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/